# Converting String I input to byte []

Tags: java, android

I want to input a String and I want to get the byte[] value for it If I give a fixed value to the String like this:

```
String myinput = "SampleString";
byte[] keyValue = myinput.getBytes();
```

I am able to get the byte[] value but if i take input from edit text like:

```
String myinput = "SampleString";
mEdit1   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
myinput = mEdit1.getText().toString();
keyValue = myinput.getBytes();
```

Then i do not get the byte[] value.

Comment: If you haven't given a value to your String, it's null. In your second example, I doubt your code even runs without a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

> *...but for some reason I am not able to do that...*

Doing this:

```
String myinput;
//get a user defined value for myinput
private   byte[] keyValue = myinput.getBytes();
```

is a predictable exception and is not even going to compile just because the variable **myinput** is not initialized...

you need to guaranty no matter what that myinput has a valid value(an initial value/ not null at best) in order to do something like

```
 keyValue = myinput.getBytes();
```

**How can you do it??**

you can set

```
String myinput = null
```

and check that is  not null before getting the bytes

Comment: I have checked for null at every point, I input the String "myinput" in one Activity which is then passed to another activity, and the result shows that no byte[] operation is done, but i can see the string in the textview, so the value is not null.